# Eclipse Neon dark theme - black font on the top bar

Tags: eclipse

I use eclipse neon 4.6.3 on RHEL 7.2

I switched to the dark scheme and my top bar (where all the File etc. dropdowns reside) looks like this:

[image]

How can it be solved?

Comment: Switch the whole OS to a dark theme or upgrade to Eclipse Photon which will be released tomorrow and use `GTK_THEME`: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#gtk3-theme-override-support

Comment: I changed the theme to Oxygen and restarted eclipse, but the font color did not change... I think I'll check out Photon in some time...

Comment: You might want to try the DevStyle plugin from Genuitec (which I work for). https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle